# Keep background-color while overlapping a picture

Tags: html

how can I overlap

```html
 <p style="background-color:red; width:168px; padding:10px; margin-top:-168px;" class="kasten">
```

this p tag on a picture and keep the background-color:red?

Because the background gets transparent when it overlaps the picture...

Thanks for your answers!

Cheers,
Till

Comment: Don't see a picture?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of margin-top, try using:

```
position: relative;
top: -168px;
```

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prvWVo

Answer (score 2):

I can't figure out if you want the `p` elements background transparent or not so I'll give you two solutions.
If you want to keep the background, not transparent while overlapping:

HTML

```
<div id="overlap">
  <p>Hello everyone, my background is transparent</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlap {
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Now for a transparent background
HTML

```
<div id="overlap">
  <p>Hello everyone, my background is transparent</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlap {
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

So what we've done here is set a height for the background image, which you need at the moment because there is not much populating the div at the moment.
Then we set a `background` property, give it the url we want, in this case I chose a kitten, `no-repeat center center fixed` this is important because

- `no-repeat` We do not want the image repeating
- `center` We want the image to center horizontally and vertically
- `fixed` You can remove this, I tend to but some like it

Next we need to set the `background-size`

- `background-size: cover` Play with this, common values are `contain` and `cover`

Finally for our `p` tag.
What depending on what you want to achieve (transparent or not) is as simple as changing the `background-color` value.

- `background-color: red` simple solid red background
- `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5)` set the red, green, blue and alpha where alpha represent transparency.
- Valid entries for alpha are 0 - 1, 1 being solid, 0 meaning transparent.